# Navigation properties not loading properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My context looks like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    //DbSet properties
}
```

so, lazy loading is enabled.

I have following class:

```
public class Home
{
    private ICollection<Slide> _slides;

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Header")]
    public int? HeaderID { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public ICollection<Slide> Slides
    {
        get { return _slides ?? (_slides = new List<Slide>()); }
        set { _slides = value; }
    }

    public Content Header { get; set; }
}
```

Note that both navigation properties `Header` and `Slides` are used *without* `virtual` keyword. [As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi) when we don't use `virtual` keyword - properties should load eagerly.

However, when I get my `Home` entity from database, both my navigation properties are `null` (but property `HeaderID` has value).
Even if I switch to `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` - preperties not loaded - they still `null`.

Here is how I get my data from db (using repository pattern):

```
public static Home GetHomeComponent(
    this IRepositoryAsync<Home> repository)
{
   var result = repository
       .Query()
       .Select()
       .First();
   return result;
}
```

I solved my problem with `Include` properties:

```
public static Home GetHomeComponent(
    this IRepositoryAsync<Home> repository)
{
   var result = repository
       .Query()
       .Include(x => x.Header)
       .Include(x=>x.Slides)
       .Select()
       .First();
   return result;
}
```

However it's not convenient for me (since I have too much navigation properties to load).

**So, my question is:**
I *don't* use `virtual` keyword - but why my navigation properties not loading eagerly?
Or I'm doing something wrong? Is there any other way to load my navigation properties without using `Include`?

Comment: if you dont want lazyLoading, why do you set it to true ?

Comment: @jony89, because I have many other classes/prepoerties for which I want lazy loading be enabled. I thought `virtual` keyword can control how my data loads - lazy or eagerly, but for some reason it's not working (and my Q is _why it's not working?_)... Btw, as I mentioned in my question, even swithcing to `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` doesn't solve my problem - properties still returns `null`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't use the `virtual` keyword it only means that once you try to access the non-virtual property it wont be loaded from the database but you will get a `Null` .

It doesn't mean you will have all the properties of the entities populated right away, to populate `Slides` for E.G in your code, you have to use .Include() - this is eager loading, to load the property by your self before it used .

You can make a generic function that will populate the required properties by the arguments it gets ( using params ) see here for more details :

[EntityFramework Eager Load all Navigation Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804850/entityframework-eager-load-all-navigation-properties)

Comment: Hm..you're right, it was my misunderstanding of meaning of `virtual` keyword.. I've just tried `public virtual Content Header { get; set; }` and it works! As a conclusion, am I right that we use `virtual` keyword for specifying that we want to load this property from db _anyway_ (lazy or eagerly depending on `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true / false;`)?

Comment: yes, the virtual keyword gives you two things : (1) LazyLoading yes or not... (2) it lets EntityFramework track on your properties ( EF can override the propeties once they are virtual) and this way it optimizing its queries, such as if only one field in a whole entity was change EF will know to update this field only - instead of updating the whole row.

Comment: I have similar problem, although i have the Navigational Entity defined as virtual by EF6 itself through the database first approach, the entity returns null. I even tried the this.configuration.LazyLoadingEnable=true, but that too didn't helped. Can anyone help me here?