# Explicitly load all navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

EF Core recently added explicitly load the navigation properties of an object;

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext()) {
    var blog = db.Blogs.Find(1);

    db.Entry(blog).Collection(b => b.Posts).Load();
    db.Entry(blog).Reference(b => b.Author).Load();
}
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/

This is obviously verbose, and I don't wish to do these checks every time. Is there any extension methods or complementary NuGet packages available to get around these shortcomings?

I realise this is a common question, but not for EF Core.

[EntityFramework Eager Load all Navigation Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804850/entityframework-eager-load-all-navigation-properties)

Comment: Does `.Include(..)` not work in core? ie. `db.Blogs.Include(m => m.Posts).Include(m => m.Author).Find(1);`

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to get around explicitly specifying the entities I want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: Ah, sorry, so your question is how to load all of the nav props off that model. I misread the title and tried to just make it simpler. I could think of a simple way to do it w/ Reflection, but not sure there's a built in method even for old EF. EDIT: Even the question you linked to would work for Core as you're still specifying what to load. EDIT2: I could be wrong, but I think `.Include(..)` is faster than loading individually too as they'll form part of the initial query run.

Comment: Loading them all this way is about the same as just using lazy loading (separate query would be made for each navigation property). So why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Evk Because EF Core currently does not support lazy loading?

Comment: @IvanStoev I guess I'd better not commenting\answering EF Core questions any more, since even basic assumptions fail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments I'm fairly confident (though my usage of EF Core is limited) that this can't be done automatically through standard mapping of navigation properties. Also using `.Load` is less efficient (and much longer) than using `.Include` as you'll be running multiple queries just like using the lazy-loading navigation property itself.

There are 2 ways I can think of to approach the problem of not wishing to do the checks every time as per your question. The first would work for loading your `Blog` entity specifically, and the second that you could reuse across others but still requires changes to your loading.

1; Extension Method to load all related entities, something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<Blog> EagerWhere(this DbSet<Blogs> dbset, Expression<Func<Blog, bool>> expr) {
    return dbset
        .Include(m => m.Posts)
        .Include(m => m.Author)
        .Where(expr);
}

// .. usage

db.Blogs.EagerWhere(m => m.Id == 1);
```

(Note that I wrote this as `EagerWhere` so you have more control over the query so it's more reusable rather than a simple `Find` replacement)

2; Write a custom attribute, and write a method used similar to the above that performs the same action as `.Find(..)` but uses Reflection to find the properties with your custom attribute, and passes them into `.Include(..)` recursively.

I won't write an example for that as I'm not sure it's worth the effort due to the (normally) limited amount of entities created.

Comment: Afaik dotnet core does not support reflection propertyinfo yet.

Comment: @alanh Hmm, I thought it did. It's missing some things for sure, but nothing as critical as this. I can't say for sure though, I haven't had chance to get to grips with Core again since the RC2.

Answer (score 1):

Now, in ef core5.0, you can use this code

```cs
//in OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<XXX>().Navigation(t => t.XX).AutoInclude();
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This is not available in EF Core 5. It is in EF Core 6.

Comment: If you're using the EF-Core scaffolding that overwrites the dbcontext everyone you re-generate you can create a partial class of the dbcontext and then put this in `partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder builder)`.  Works like a charm.

Comment: @johnye2e ef core5 has documentation about it, though I'm not sure if it's available in 5 https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.navigationbuilder.autoinclude?view=efcore-5.0